# Custom content provider: error from the emulator (failed to find provider info)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

So I created a simple content provider, but I've got an error :

> Failed to find provider info for com.b1.BooksContentProvider

I have 2 AVD names for 2.2 and 3.2 versions (I wrote random names for both of them)
3.2 because I use the v4 `Fragment` support
So, I don't know if the problem comes from the manifest, or from the version I'm using to launch the emulator.

here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.b1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MyBooksActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/mt_books" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/mt_books" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.b1.BooksContentProvider"
            android:name="com.b1.BooksContentProvider"></provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the first part of my content provider :

```
public class BooksContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    BooksDataBase mDB;
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.b1.MyBooksActivity";
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "books";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content:// " + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH);
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
        + "/mt_books";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
        + "/mt_books";

    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    private static final int BOOK_DIR = 101;
    private static final int BOOK_ITEM = 102;

    static
    {
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, BOOK_DIR);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH+"/#", BOOK_ITEM);
    }
```

Thanks for your help

---

UPDATE

---

Ok, one of the possible mistake was :
i forgot to "import" the different classes
also, in the fragment XML : the LinearLayout did not work, i had to put a "TextView" alone in the XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.b1.MyBooksActivity";
```

That is not the same authority as you have in your `<provider>` element:

```
<provider
        android:authorities="com.b1.BooksContentProvider"
        android:name="com.b1.BooksContentProvider"></provider>
```

They need to match.

Comment: thanks, i edited the code, but it's odd, i have the same error. I cleaned the project, restarted eclipse, but still the same exact error. Any other idea?

Comment: @Paul: Off the top of my head, no. That error is pretty much always because of a `CONTENT_URI`/authority mismatch, AFAIK.

Comment: okay... would you know any way to debug this? also, would it help if i'd copy and paste the whole code of my contentProvider to show you?

Comment: @Paul: "would you know any way to debug this?" -- find some other sample app that works, then start figuring out where your implementation differs from it. Here is one: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ContentProvider/ConstantsPlus

Comment: thanks, i appreciate, just one thing though: you did not specify in "delete" if the deleted element was an "item" or a "dir". I'm a bit confused with this : for my Books, why/when should i use "dir", and when should i use the "item" mime type? i did not really understand it from the doc i think. Thanks for your help, i'll try to find the answer with your code tomorrow.

Comment: @Paul: The `dir` MIME type would represent your entire collection (e.g., `CONTENT_URI`). The `item` MIME type would represent an individual instance (e.g., `CONTENT_URI` plus instance ID).

Comment: Thanks, okay, i've got a last question, what does `sqlite_master` stand for, in your `Provider.java`? it seems to be the table, but then you write `CREATE TABLE constants` ... Thanks for your answer